# Group and Sort based on JOIN and 2 different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Here is my current SQL code, which orders posts by created_at column:

```
    select users.name as user_name, * 
    from posts
    join users on users.id = posts.user_id
    order by posts.created_at desc;
```

- This is returning recently created posts order
- Now I also want to group my posts by user_name, keeping up the same order.

Example:

| user_name | post | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 2021-09-13 |
| B | P | 2021-09-12 |
| A | Y | 2021-09-12 |
| B | Q | 2021-09-11 |
| A | Z | 2021-09-11 |

**Requirement**

- Group posts by user_name, order by created_at
- Also Note that, `created_at` sort order should get the first priority, and then group user with order by `created_at desc`.

| user_name | post | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 2021-09-13 |
| A | Y | 2021-09-12 |
| A | Z | 2021-09-11 |
| B | P | 2021-09-12 |
| B | Q | 2021-09-11 |

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to order by username, you would use:

```
order by user_name, created_at desc
```

If you want the most recent user first, you can use window functions:

```
order by max(created_at) over (partition by user_name) desc,
         user_name,
         created_at desc
```

Comment: I used both functions, and actually `created_at` order is not correct in both case. Bacially, Record should always show recent record first, and then it needs to group supplier keeping that order.

Comment: To provide more info @gordon-linoff first record it should show is always today's record for example, but if I try above solution, suppliers are grouped properly, but created_at dates are yesterday's date first, and then in middle of records, I see group suppliers with today's date. https://i.imgur.com/Cm62eyT.png check screenshot for example

Comment: @przbadu . . . .Totally lost.  There is no supplier in your data and **your** query is ordering by `created_at`.

Comment: sorry, I referenced wrong column name here, I will update my comment, but I mean to say `user_name`

Comment: also I updated the ticket to include more info, let me know if I have to add more information that I am missing.

Comment: That screenshot has result of `order by max(posts.created_at) over (partition by users.name), users.name, posts.created_at desc` https://i.imgur.com/Cm62eyT.png

Comment: @przbadu And if you add `desc` to first ordering expression, what happens?

Comment: @Arvo If I put `order by max(posts.created_at) over (partition by users.name), posts.created_at desc, users.name` https://i.imgur.com/31FvXJu.png

Comment: @Arvo got you, yes if I put `order by max(posts.created_at) over (partition by users.name) desc, users.name, posts.created_at desc`, it seems to give me expected result. Thanks a lot.